# Using SSH key in bitbucket?

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys, bitbucket.org

I'm trying to add SSH key to bitbucket.org account, but with no success.

I added my public key in bitbucket profile settings, then changed my remote URL to be SSH.

But trying to connect to remote, gives me access error. Though I can use same ssh key on my other remote servers just fine (not for git but for SSH login to server). So do I need to create new ssh key pair or am I missing something here?

```
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

P.S. In debug I see that it is offering `id_rsa` as public key. Does it mean it is looking for wrong location (or it should be like that?). Cause my public key is in a file named `id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: `id_rsa` in the transcript is ok. What command did you run? Or rather do you get this result for `ssh git@bitbucket.org -vvv`?

Comment: @techraf I ran this: `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` as written in: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html

Comment: And you are working directly on the machine you are trying to reach BitBucket? No SSH session in between? If no, then it looks like there is little room for mistake. Try with a different key, check you have no entries in `~/.ssh/config` that might get in the way (pay attention to wildcards).

Comment: @techraf Yes I'm working on my laptop and there is no SSH session in between. Also I don't even have any `config` file in `~/.ssh`.

Comment: I was using my `username@url`, instead of `git@url`, changing to `git` works fine now.

Comment: I'll refrain from commenting...